# htaccess one url to subfolder on domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to get this result on htacces configuration

if (www.domain.de/some/projects/)
    execute on webspace root/some/subdir/projetcs/index.php
else 
    execute on webspace root/index.php

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some/subdir/projects/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /some/subdir/projects/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I only want that 1 Link is redirected to a subforder on the webspace, hope someone can help me, I am trying more then 1 day now.

Comment: How can i achieve that i load a other php script then index.php in the subfolder? like

Comment: RewriteRule ^ /some/subdir/projects/web/app.php [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

The first section was wrong in several aspects:

1. the request you expect (some/projects) has not be tested in the condition, not the one you want to rewrite to.
2. since you are using `.htaccess` style syntax you are working on *relative* paths, so you must not test for the leading slash (`/`).

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some/projects
RewriteRule ^ /some/subdir/projects [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

I also added the `R` flag to force external redirects, this appears to me what you want to do, though I may be wrong there.

*Note: this does not consider which project is actually requested in the first block, since the description in your question does not say so.*

Comment: The url wasnt match, he executed the normal index.php

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some/projects
RewriteRule ^ /some/projects [L,R=301] this worked

Comment: @Wykk OK, though to me this sounds like you are _not_ using `.htaccess` style files, as you stated in the question, but have these rules inside your http servers host configuration. and I fail to understand the RewriteRule you now specified. I'd say it does _not_ rewrite, since it is a rewrite to the same path which should result in an endless loop...

Comment: Hmm i use .htaccess file and the rewrite works now. No loop to see.

Comment: @Wykk Ah, sorry, my bad: I confused `REQUEST_URI` with `FILE_PATH` and the like. The later are relative, `REQUEST_URI` obviously is absolute, you were and are right there. However I still do not understand that `RewriteRule` you now came out with. For me this contradicts to what you request in your question: rewriting `/some/projects` to `/some/subdir/projetcs`. I cannot see you doing that with the rule you posted in the comment above. But OK, if it works for you... :-) Have fun!

Comment: Nope it doesnt worked, i dont need the roule to get acces of this :( 
The question is still open, one more problem there:
i have a link: /some that should match the index.php and /some/projects should match the /some/subdir/projects anyone idea? :(

Comment: Sure, this is possible, but you will have to define more specific what you mean by `/some`. Just that path, nothing behind? Or anything following that _except_ for `/some/projects`? Sorry, but rules have to be specific, so to create them you have to explain precisely, not just roughly, what it actually is you want to implement.

Comment: Its just the Link www.domain.de/some/projekt that should match the files on webspace root/some/projects
Then in have a normal link that should match the file root/index.php with all other links and www.domain.de/some too

Comment: Sorry, this did not help: what is a "normal link"? The rules as shown in the answer above rewrite everything below `/some/projects` to `/some/subdir/projects`. They certainly do _not_ rewrite everything under `/some` to `/some/subdir/projects`, _except_ for `/some/project`. So `/some` is rewritten to `index.php`.

Comment: However what I just saw is this: The last RewriteRule shown in the answer above rewrote to `index.php`. I changed that to `/index.php` now. It _might_ be that this has caused some effect. Other than that I have no idea what might be wrong for you, except that you are not using the rules as shown above, according to your comments here. Since no one here can see what rules you now actually use I suggest you post a new question about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Arkascha i have this on my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/some/projects
RewriteRule ^ /some/projects [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

But now i have Problem that all works just the LINK: www.domain.de/some dont work coz there is no indes and i wana get the index from root/index coz there is a cms with the link inside.

But if i go on

> www.domain.de/some/projects

i wana fetch the

> root/some/projects

coz for this link i have a framework that should display just this one link, and if its a other link then the

> "www.domain.de/some/projects"

i wana get the

> root/index.php

from webspace.

I hope you understand me now and can help me or some others, i need to finish my project today and this dont work ;(

EDIT:
I only have this now in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

This execute both links: www.domain.de/some/projects and all other except of 
www.domain.de/some.

In root/some on webspace is no index.php thats why he tell me permission deny.

Error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /some/ on this server.

Comment: Sorry, you should not post an answer if you want to ask something.

Comment: Besides: I will say something is very odd there: the rewriting of `/some/projects` to `/some/projects` will create an endless loop. Why shouldn't it? Apart from the fact that it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: The description here is very vague, hard to understand. _Maybe_ what you actually ask is that `/some` should _not_ get rewritten at all? But I can only guess that, since you are extremely vague. What does "the LINK: www.domain.de/some dont work" mean? "don't work" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time to fix an issue. _Be precise_ in your question, otherwise it is not possible to help. Sorry.

Comment: I think the question is just: I wana fetch all links to index.php on root webspace. But only the Link: www.domain.de/some/projects should fetch the root/some/projects/index.php. Sry for my bad english, i really trying to explain my problem. 
If i execute the link www.domain.de/some i get this server error: 
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /some/ on this server.

Comment: Ah, so you get an error? Why don't you say so in your question/answer? This is not an issue of language perfection, just keep in mind that you always have to specify _all_ relevant information in an explicit manner. Others cannot guess things or look onto your system. About the error itself: it indicates that your file permissions deny access to that folder. Question is whether that is raised because `/some` is _not_ rewritten to `/index.php` (which it clearly should be according to the rules) or if the index script itself tries to access things in that folder but is denied. Only you can tell.

Comment: It looks like its not rewritten to /index.php coz if i place in /some a index.php this will be executed .. as example an echo 'string'. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, sure: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` explicitly says: if the directory does not exist. since it exists, no rewriting is done. So you probably want to remove those one or both RewriteCond's?

Comment: I edit my answer for complete.. if i remove the !-d line, i get an " Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you then have to prevent a rewrite loop. So instead of the `-d` condition add that one: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/index.php&

Comment: Same forbidden error ;( with "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/index.php&" instead of the -d cond. But no internal server error

Comment: Sorry, typos: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index.php$ No idea why that should lead to a "forbidden", though. Make a deep reload, clear your browser cache too.

Comment: Same forbidden error: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index.php$, i cleared cache and made deep reload :(

Comment: I only now see that you removed the `R=301` again. Without that no loop will occur. No idea why you should get a forbidden error. sure that is for the same target as before? Anyway: this is something you have to fiddle out yourself locally. You have to understand what you implement there anyway.

Comment: I have only 1 question left. If i browse to link www.domain.de/some who will be execute the htaccess in root/ or in /some? Or its just 1 in the root?

Comment: If the request gets rewritten, then `/index.php`, otherwise any index in the `/some` folder. Whether it ets rewritten obviously depends in your current RewriteCond's.